# How to change or update string of array with Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

Here is the array:

```
    var newArray = [

                    "self.Button.setTitle(\"\", for: .normal)", 
                    "self.Button.setTitle(\"\", for: .normal)", 
                    "self.Button.setTitle(\"\", for: .normal)", 
                    "self.Button.setTitle(\"\", for: .normal)"
                    ]
```

I would like to update or print it out like this:

```
                    "self.aButton.setTitle("", for: .normal)"
                    "self.bButton.setTitle("", for: .normal)"
                    "self.cButton.setTitle("", for: .normal)"
                    "self.dButton.setTitle("", for: .normal)"
```

Any ideas will be appreciated.

**Update**: What I tried is:

```
var anotherArray = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

for value in newArray {

    for anotherValue in anotherArray {
     print(i.replacingOccurrences(of: "Button", with: value))

  }
}
```

But it will print out:

```
self.aButton.setTitle("", for: .normal)
self.bButton.setTitle("", for: .normal)
self.cButton.setTitle("", for: .normal)
self.dButton.setTitle("", for: .normal)
self.aButton.setTitle("", for: .normal)
self.bButton.setTitle("", for: .normal)
self.cButton.setTitle("", for: .normal)
self.dButton.setTitle("", for: .normal)
self.aButton.setTitle("", for: .normal)
self.bButton.setTitle("", for: .normal)
self.cButton.setTitle("", for: .normal)
self.dButton.setTitle("", for: .normal)
self.aButton.setTitle("", for: .normal)
self.bButton.setTitle("", for: .normal)
self.cButton.setTitle("", for: .normal)
self.dButton.setTitle("", for: .normal)
```

What I want is:

```
                    "self.aButton.setTitle("", for: .normal)"
                    "self.bButton.setTitle("", for: .normal)"
                    "self.cButton.setTitle("", for: .normal)" 
                    "self.dButton.setTitle("", for: .normal)"
```

That's why I raised the question, and I knew it didn't work, because it's in a wrong direction, so I didn't post out what I tried.

Comment: Are you trying to compile and execute arbitrary code as strings on the fly? Don't, it can be a big security problem.

Comment: @Sweeper Just want to use it in playground.

Comment: Please include your own attempts to solve it in the question.

Comment: I'm curious, what exactly are you trying to do with this? Even if you had this code-as-strings, Swift isn't a dynamic language. There's no `eval` you can use to run it.

Comment: @Alexander I'm not going to use it or run it in a production. Just trying to use it in a playground to reduce some duplicate jobs.

Comment: " to reduce some duplicate jobs." what are you trying to automate, exactly? Because this sounds very fishy.

Comment: @Alexander I'm trying to build a third-party keyboard, and a keyboard has 26 buttons. I'm trying to give every button a title. Is that clear?

Comment: Oh boy, you're very lucky. I've done something exactly like that before. Firstly, don't do this. You would be hard coding the layout. IDK who your users are, but most likely, a large portion (probably even the majority) of them don't have the same keyboard layout as you. It's much better to query the system for the system locale, and then query it for the keys that associate with each position. I implemented this (painstakingly by hand) by assigning a key code to the tag of every button. From there, I would use key codes to look up the write symbol, using `UCKeyTranslate`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197166/discussion-between-alexander-and-vincent).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a possible way:

```
var letters: [Character] = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

let insertionIndex = newArray[0]
    .index(newArray[0].startIndex, offsetBy: 5)

for index in newArray.indices {
    newArray[index].insert(letters[index], at: insertionIndex)
}
```

And you could check the result this way:

```
newArray.forEach { print($0) }
```

Which prints:

> ```
> self.aButton.setTitle("", for: .normal)
> self.bButton.setTitle("", for: .normal)
> self.cButton.setTitle("", for: .normal)
> self.dButton.setTitle("", for: .normal)
> ```